# Relacionamento de tabelas usando FK's

Tags: php, mysql, relacionamento

Estou fazendo um sistema que o usuário crie uma conta e selecione os filmes que ele já assistiu.

Tenho uma tabela no MySQL filmes para cadastrar todos os filmes do site e uma tabela generos que está só os gêneros dos filmes (ação, aventura...) e queria saber como ligar essas tabelas para que eu cadastre um gênero novo e apareça na página do cadastro de filmes no select do genero, como se faz isso?

Queria saber também como vou fazer que apareça os filmes cadastrados e as suas informações no perfil da pessoa para que ela possa marcar que assistiu?

Comment: É muito amplo. Experimente fazer perguntas mais específicas ou utilizar a busca para encontrar perguntas que porventura já existam. Para não dizer que esse é um comentário inútil, dou uma dica, procure por CRUD. Boa sorte.

Comment: Tem vários tutoriais em vídeo na internet sobre sistemas básicos de cadastro, postar qualquer um deles aqui faria a resposta ficar monstruosa e não teria o mesmo efeito de ver um vídeo. Procure pelos termos: PHP MySQL CRUD

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar de 4 tabelas, a de **usuário**, **filme**, **gênero** e **filmes vistos**.

Usei como referencia
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

O usuario ligação de um para vários em filmes vistos, filmes de 1 para vários filmes vistos, genero de 1 para vários filmes vistos.

O código mysql fica assim:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario (
id INT NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
//OUTROS DADOS DO USUARIO
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE FilmeVistos(
id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (idUsuario) REFERENCES Usuario(id),
FOREIGN KEY (idFilme) REFERENCES Filmes(id)
);


CREATE TABLE Filmes (
id INT NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
//OUTROS DADOS DO Filme
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY (idGenero) REFERENCES Genero(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Genero (
id INT NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//OUTROS DADOS DO Genero
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

//apareça os filmes cadastrados
SELECT * FROM Filmes;
```

Coloque esse select em um campo para o usuário marcar e faça o insert no Filmes Vistos.

Qualquer dúvida consulte o link abaixo para fazer conexão no banco com php.

http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Como_conectar_a_um_banco_MySQL_atrav%C3%A9s_de_script_PHP